# Hangman Game in C#

Tags: c#, hangman

I've created a simple Hangman game (not finished yet).

- What could I improve? (This isn't intended to be object-oriented but suggestions on that are also welcome.)
- What are its flaws?

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    private ReadFromFile readFromFile;
    private Random random;
    private string word;
    private int wrongGuesses;
    private int amountOfLettersRevealed;
    private bool wordRevealed;
    private const int MAX_WRONG_GUESSES = 9;

    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadWords("words");
        selectRandomWord();
    }

    private void loadWords(string fileLocation)
    {
        readFromFile = new ReadFromFile(fileLocation);
        readFromFile.read();
    }

    private void selectRandomWord()
    {
        random = new Random();

        string[] words = readFromFile.lines;
        word = words[random.Next(words.Length)];
    }

    private void letter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wordRevealed)
            return;

        Button button = (Button)sender;

        char letter = char.Parse(button.Name.Substring(6).ToLower());

        guessLetter(letter);
        buttonClicked(button);
    }

    private void guessLetter(char letter)
    {
        if (!word.Contains(letter))
        {
            // wrong guess
            wrongGuesses++;
        }
        else
        {
            // right guess
            for (int index = 0; index < word.Length; index++)
            {
                if (letter == word[index])
                {
                    revealLetter(index, letter);
                    amountOfLettersRevealed++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (amountOfLettersRevealed == word.Length)
        {
            wordRevealed = true;
            gameWon();
        }
        if (wrongGuesses == MAX_WRONG_GUESSES)
        {
            gameOver();
        }
    }

    private void buttonClicked(Button button)
    {
        button.Enabled = false;
        Image image = loadImage(button.Name.Substring(6) + "_HOV");
        button.BackgroundImage = image;
    }

    private void revealLetter(int index, char letter)
    {

    }

    private void gameWon()
    {
        playSound("youwin");
    }

    private void gameOver()
    {         
        playSound("gameover");
    }

    private Image loadImage(string location)
    {
        object o = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(location);
        return (Image) o;
    }

    private void playSound(string sound)
    {
        SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(sound + ".wav");
        sp.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `private void loadWords(string fileLocation)`

Follow [standard naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043): `private void LoadWords(string fileLocation)` - same for the rest of your methods.

In `private void guessLetter(char letter)` there is the following code:

> ```
> if (amountOfLettersRevealed == word.Length)
> {
>     wordRevealed = true;
>     gameWon();
> }
> if (wrongGuesses == MAX_WRONG_GUESSES)
> {
>     gameOver();
> }
> ```

Presumably if `amountOfLettersRevealed == word.Length` then `wrongGuesses != MAX_WRONG_GUESSES`? In that case it seems to make more sense to use `else if`, rather than evaluating the second expression even if the first is true. (Why would you call `gameWon()` and then check if you lost too?)

Also I think that code should not be in that method at all. The method is called `guessLetter`. It should handle the logic of guessing the letter. Checking whether the player has won or lost is not "guessing the letter".

Also it seems strange to have the `letter_Click` call a `buttonClicked` method. Initially I thought that was the button's click event handler due to the similarity between this method's name and the default name for a click event handler for a nameless button. I would maybe call that method `UpdateButtonBackground` or whatever that describes what that method actually does, since it's not an event handler.

Comment: I am sorry, I am used to Java (camelCase). I'll change that to PascalCase. | That's completely true, I hadn't noticed that. | I understand, the name of the method doesn't suit its behaviour. Would you recommend to create 2 extra methods called "checkIfWon" and "checkIfLost" and call them instead? | `UpdateButtonBackground` still doesn't describe its behaviour since I disable the button too. | Thank you so much for your feedback!

Comment: I'd be inclined to put the code to check if the player has won or lost in a single method, and possibly called by the same code block that calls `guessLetter()` (not called from within `guessLetter()` itself).

Comment: What approach do you recommend? Call `checkIfWonOrLost` in the `letter_Click` method?

Comment: Yes, why not. If `letter_Click` calls `guessLetter` then I think it should also call `checkIfWonOrLost`. So from that location you can see that the letter is checked, and then the outcome is checked.

Comment: Ok :). Thanks man! Here is the updated version: http://pastebin.com/yk7wJ0wn

Answer (score 0):

In short methods like this one:

```
private Image loadImage(string location)
{
    object o = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(location);
    return (Image) o;
}
```

I would just do this:

```
private Image loadImage(string location)
{
    return (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(location);
}
```

But it looks like you are only calling this method once, so there is really no need to have a separate method for this.

You should probably also implement the `RevealLetter` method.
I also noticed that there is no logic for showing a hidden word to the user (like how many letter are in the word to guess. Is that intentional? it might be nice to have that for the user.

Comment: I'll update that method. It was intented for many usages so that's why I created a method for it (even though I only use it once right now).


I plan to finish "RevealLetter" as soon as I finish the GUI. The amount of letters in a word will also be shown when the GUI is finished.


Thank you!